# Print Value of Bool in Rust

Tags: rust

How do I print the value of a bool in Rust?

```rust
let mut myFalseBool = false;
let mut myTrueBool = true; 
//how do I print out the value of either bool?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you print any value:

```
let foobar = true;
println!("{}", foobar);
dbg!(foobar);
```

This outputs:

```
true
[src/main.rs:4] foobar = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy 2023 way:

```
const IS_KANEKI_GHOUL: bool = true;
const IS_ICHIGO_GHOUL: bool = false;
println!("{IS_KANEKI_GHOUL}, {IS_ICHIGO_GHOUL}");
```